# Permissions Issue with tcpdump in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: tcpdump

I am creating a tcpdump file using "tcpdump tcp -w tcp1" but I can't use the -r function to read the file as it says "permissions denied". I used chmod to try and change permissions even changed group permissions and still now affect. Help! Thank you

ubuntu 20.04

root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump tcp -w tcp1
tcpdump: listening on ens33, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
985 packets captured
985 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -r tcp1
tcpdump: tcp1: Permission denied
root@ubuntu:~#

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with AppAmour - you'll need to disable it first.

There are instructions here: https://www.xmodulo.com/disable-particular-apparmor-profile-ubuntu.html

I hard to restart by box, just restarting the service didn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned - it is blocked by AppArmour.

The file will be readable by tcpdump after renaming it, adding the .pcap extension.